# Using method on variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have code:

```
a=2

def mult(a, b):
    x=a*b
    return x
```

Now instead of using it as `mult(a, 2)`, I want to use it as `a.mult(2)`. I mean something like, define class with method as my function above and right after call it on `a` variable with a syntax like `a.mult(2)`. How can I do it? Maybe some sort of duck typing, or using static or class type of methods?

Comment: Is mult(a, 2) supposed to equal 4?

Comment: You can use `a.__mul__(2)`.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? Yes, you can define a class with a ``mult`` method, and assign an instance to ``a``. Do you have trouble doing that? If so, what have you tried and what problem do you have? Do you want something else? If so, what exactly do you need? Is ``a`` always going to be a builtin, and does the "function" correspond to a method of that type?

Comment: Python doesn't have extension methods or Uniform Function Call Syntax or anything else that would let you define your own `int` methods. Someone's going to suggest writing a subclass, but the method will only be available on instances of your subclass, and the subclass will cause compatibility problems. Just use function call syntax - it's the best available option.

Comment: It is very important that you precisely define what you want to do, not just give some example. Given ``a=2``, it is perfectly possible to do ``a.__mul__(4).__truediv__(12).__add__(4.5).as_integer_ratio()`` which is "something like" what you described. Is ``a`` a global, class or local variable? Is it a builtin? Does assignment, or also lookup have to respect the initial type assigned?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thank you for your comment. I understand issue of my question. I will create new question with more details per your advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class to that has an attribute to contain your number. Then have a method that you can call on the object.

```
class myNum: #myNum object
    def __init__(self, num): #initialize
        self.num = num #init objects num attribute with parameter
    def mult(self, product): #multiple method, takes product parameter
        return self.num * product #multiply
a= myNum(2) #Create and object of the class
print(a.mult(3)) #call and print mult method
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible implementation:

```
class Num: 
    def __init__(self, val):
        self._val = val
    def mult(self, other_val): 
        return self._val * other_val

my_num = Num(5)
my_num.mult(3)
```

This results, of course, in 15.

Answer (score 0):

There are these class method-wrappers for ints:

```
__mul__:     to multiply
__add__:     to add
__sub__:     to subtract
__truediv__: to divide
```

and more.